# Adding total count of observations to barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am currently working with survey data with 250 columns. A sample of my data looks like this:

```
q1 <- factor(c("yes","yes","no","yes",NA,"yes","no","yes"))
q2 <- factor(c("Albania","USA","Albania","Albania","UK",NA,"UK","Albania"))
q3 <- factor(c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0))
q4 <- factor(c(0,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,0,0))
q5 <- factor(c("Dont know","Prefer not to answer","Agree","Disagree",NA,"Agree","Agree",NA))
q6 <- factor(c(1,NA,3,5,800,NA,900,2))

data <- data.frame(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6)
```

In order to loop through all columns and create list of barplots showing distribution of answers, I used code below:

```
barplot_list <- lapply(names(data), function(variable) {
  ggplot(
    data = data,
    mapping = aes(.data[[variable]])
  ) +
    geom_bar(width = 0.6, fill = "#0096FF") +
    labs(x = variable, y = "response count") +
    geom_text(aes(label=..count..),stat='count',position=position_dodge(0.9),hjust=-0.1)+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
    coord_flip()
})
```

Now I want to add total count of observations to each barplot. Total count can be shown in legend or inside chart or in caption. I tried adding following line of code:
`geom_text(stat = "count",aes(label = after_stat(sum(count))))`

But this shows total count on top of each bar. Is there a way to modify my code so that "Total = N" (N standing for total observations for each column(excluding NAs) in dataset) is shown somewhere in the plot?
Thank you very much beforehand!

Comment: How about if you just add it to the y axis label: `labs(x = variable, y=paste0("response count (Total=",nrow(data),")"))`

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to get total count which doesn't include NAs? For example for q4 Total = 4 would be displayed. Sorry for not mentioning this part in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the number of observations is going to be the same for every plot, because it's the number of rows of the dataframe... (8 in your example)

can add it in the caption like this:

```
+ labs(caption = paste("Total =", nrow(data)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is it possible to get total count which doesn't include NAs? For example for q4 Total = 4 would be displayed. Sorry for not mentioning this part in my question

Comment: then use 

sum(!is.na(data[[variable]]))

instead of nrow(data)